# AngularJs, ng-if to change text?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm given the following code

```
 <h2>{{ownername}} Online Bookshop</h2>
 <input placeholder="type your name" ng-model="ownername" >
```

Which outputs 'Online Bookshop'

and if I input 'Fred' it outputs 'Fred Online Bookshop'

Without using jQuery, and doing things the angular way, how would I change the code so that a possessive apostrophe and the letter s were added when input is not empty?

EG

Online Bookshop  when input is empty, and

Fred's Online Bookshop  when input contains 'Fred' string

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Remember that the scope is just a place where you can evaluate things. So thats exactly what we can do. The `?` is a ternary operator of the form: `(expression)?<true clause>:<false clause>;` and is equal to:

```
if(expression) { <true clause>; }
else { <false clause>; }
```

Modified code:

```
<h2>{{ ownername.length ? ownername + "'s " : "" }}Online Bookshop</h2>
<input placeholder="type your name" ng-model="ownername" >
```

**Edit:**
Even though this works, its probably better as others point out to hide the logic from the view. This can be done by calling a scope function, or applying a filter to the variable to transform it as expected.

Comment: except you can't use ternary operator in angular this way.

Comment: this will give you a lexer error :  Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 18-18 [?] in expression [ ownername.length ? ownername + "'s " : "" ].

Comment: @Quad AngularJS has supported the ternary operator [for more than a year](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/6798fec4390a72b7943a49505f8a245b6016c84b)

Comment: @sabhiram sorry was not aware my test was using 1.1.x, upvoted answer

Comment: ternary will work but it's almost always a bad idea to add logic to your view. @theJoeBiz is right, this is *exactly* what angular filters are for.

Comment: Although you can do this, adding logic to your view is somewhat bad practice. I would recommend looking into defining a filter which transforms your data appropriately.

Answer (score 4):

Use a filter!

```
app.filter('possessive', function() {
  return function(val) {
    if (!val) return '';
    return val + '\'s';
  };
});
```

Then:

```
<h2>{{ ownername | possessive }} Online Bookshop</h2>
```

Comment: This worked for me. I needed to change true/false to yes/no on a bool.